# Better practice in list/array initialization

Tags: flutter, dart

In creating a not-null empty list or array, which is advised between these two.

```
List newList = List();
List<Obstacle> obstacles = List<Obstacle>();
```

or

```
List newList = [];
List<Obstacle> obstacles = [];
```

or they both do the exact same thing and have the same effect on processing and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declarative vs. Literal Constructors**

From my knowledge, there isn't any difference between using a literal constructor, `[]` and a declarative constructor `List()`.

Both have the same result, but I would suggest that you use the declarative `List()` constructor. Because the literal constructor is used for predefining a few values in a list. Like: `List myList = [1,2,3];`.

So if you want to create a non-null list, use:

```
List myList = List();
```

But if you want to define some initial values for your list, then use the literal constructor:

```
List myList = [1,2,3];
```

**Generics**

***Quick Info: Lists are generics, Maps are also Generics.***

A Generic is basically when you want to pass an Object Type as a parameter to a class or function or type definition. Smart programmers use this to write reusable code.

For example, I have a `Response` class which I use all over my app, the `Response` class has a data variable. But I want it to be able to tell Dart where the `Response` class carries a `data` of type `String` or a data of type `int`.

So to achieve this I would make my `Response` class a `Generic`.

Here is an example of a Generic response class. The data variable can be set as needed for any situation in my app.

```
Response<String> response = Response<String>();

//Defining a Generic's type is optional.
//So both statements work.
Response response = Response();

class Response<T> {
  T data;
}
```

**Why Generics?**
So that you get Dart's amazing static compile safety features. Generics give the flexibility of reusing a class for multiple situations but still give you powerful compile safety.

So when declaring a `List` if you define that it's a `List<int>`. The compiler will make sure that you don't accidentally try inserting a `String` in it.

Comment: Thanks. Are you really 14?

Comment: Haha, I'm 16 now, that bio was updated 2 years ago. Now I have 3 years of Flutter experience! Check my website: https://www.musausman.com

Comment: Here a website I made in Flutter Web: https://thefoodapp.co

Comment: Really nice stuff man. https://musausman.com/convert-website-to-mobile-app/ there's a tiny little typo on the "internet detection" write up on this page. Really cool website overall.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!